# get array element based on a property in emberjs template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have an array `someArray` and I try to get its nth element, where n based on row's property.

```
{{#each data as |row|}}
  {{someArray.[row.property]}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember.js' HTMLBars has a [`get` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get) that you can use. It doesn't support integer indices, but if you convert it to a string, with the clever use of `concat`, it should work:

```
{{#each data as |row|}}
  {{get someArray (concat row.property)}}
{{/each
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars has a [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper:

```
{{#each data as |row|}}
    {{lookup ../someArray row.property}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I'd like to note that the question is tagged `ember.js`, and `lookup` isn't defined there.